# Group by value range and drop duplicates rows in Hql/Sql

Tags: sql, hive, hql

I have a sample data like this. What I need is that, for every two rows in which 0 <= `A` value difference <= 1, (e.g. `0 <= row1.A - row1.B <=1` ) drop duplicates values by `B` and `C`, keep the smaller `A` row. Can this be done in Hql without using user defiend functions?

```
A B C
1 2 3
4 2 3
2 1 1
3 1 1
2 2 3
3 0 2
```

Results:

```
A B C
1 2 3
2 1 1
3 0 2
4 2 3
```

Comment: What is this supposed to mean:   `0 <= A value difference <= 1`?  Are the rows in order?  If so, how is the order specified?

Comment: @GordonLinoff It means two rows, row1 and row2,  satisfy 0<= row1.A - row2.A <= 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want rows where A value on a B/C row differs from the previous A value by at least 2.

You can do this using `lag()` and then some logic:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, lag(A) over (partition by B, C order by A) as prev_a
      from t
     ) t
where prev_a is null or A > prev_a + 1;
```

Comment: Works. Shame that I didn't come up with this.